# What is the Laplace transform of the distribution $\delta \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$?

Tags: laplace-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Trying to find numerocity of the roots of the function $\cos(1/x)$ I stumbled at the following problem: what is the Laplace transform of the distribution $\delta \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting, we have that

$$\delta\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = \sum_{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x_k}\right)=0}\frac{1}{\left|\left[\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]_{x=x_k}^{'}\right|}\delta(x-x_k) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}}\frac{4}{(\pi+2\pi k)^2}\cdot\delta\left(x-\frac{2}{\pi+2\pi k}\right)$$

Since the Laplace transform is one sided, implicitly the domain of the delta is $[0,\infty)$ and the summation will exclude $k\in\Bbb{Z}^-$. By the linearity of the Laplace transform we obtain

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\delta\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right\} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4}{(\pi+2\pi k)^2}\mathcal{L}\left\{\delta\left(x-\frac{2}{\pi+2\pi k}\right)\right\}$$

$$= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4}{(\pi+2\pi k)^2} \exp\left(\frac{-2s}{\pi+2\pi k}\right)$$

Comment: @Anixx it is the Laplace transform of the function in question

Comment: Well, I did a plot of this function and it goes to $1/2$ at zero. This looks wrong as the function should go to infinity at zero, no?

Comment: It seems, some kind of regularization is involved while I wanted the full form.

Comment: @Anixx why should it go to infinity at $0$? There is no regularization, this is the exact Laplace transform and you're welcome to review the only two lines of work that are here.

Comment: Well because the integral $\int_0^\infty \delta(\cos(1/x))dx$ is infinite. For instance, the Laplace transform of $\int_0^\infty \delta(\cos x)dx$ is $\frac{1}{2} \text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)$, goes to infinity at zero.

Comment: @Anixx are you sure that the integral is infinite? You should check again (It isn't)

Comment: The function $\cos(1/x)$ has infinitely many roots. If we put a delta function spike at each root, and integral over each of them is $1$, we get infinity.

Comment: @Anixx you forgot about the Jacobian in both of your examples - your logic isn't correct in general and only happens to work for $\delta(\cos x)$ because the Jacobian for that is $1$ at each root. Using the change of variables $t = \frac{1}{x}$ you will see that $$\int_0^\infty \delta(\cos x^{-1}) dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\delta(\cos t)}{t^2}dt$$ Do you see how the second series of delta spikes is tempered by a convergent integral?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is permitted to change variables under a divergent integral...

Comment: Oh I see now, each spike is smaller and smaller. This mean I need another function.

Comment: Okay, so this means I need Laplace transform of the function $\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \delta \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}{x^2}$ so to make all delta spikes equal.